# Scipy.optimize and callback not working when using workers

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, multiprocessing

I'm using scipy.optimize ([differential evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#scipy-optimize-differential-evolution)) for optimisation. Overall works great. I've started to use the worker feature (which allows you to tell the optimisation to spin off individuals in the population into other processes, effectively parallelizing the optimisation process very easily).

I see that if I specify workers=-1, all my cores are being put to work, as they should.

The simulation is managed in a structure:

```
""" Sandbox stuff """
from scipy.optimize import *

class Simulation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def optim_manager(self):
        optimized_results = differential_evolution(self.optim_loop, 
        bounds=self.bounds, callback=self.optim_callback, workers=-1)

    def optim_loop(self, parameters):
        self.data = run_model(parameters)
        optim_value = self.calc_optim_value(self.data)

        # at this point self.data exist & is not None
        return optim_value


    def optim_callback(self,*args):
        # *args contains the parameters value for that optimal run
        optim_value = self.calc_optim_value(self.data)              # error
        write_optimisation_run_to_dictionnary(args, optim_value)
```

However, when I try to calculate the optim_value in the callback, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lancer_modele.py", line 512, in <module>
    mp.launch()
  File "lancer_modele.py", line 234, in launch
    self.do_optim_ghosts()
  File "lancer_modele.py", line 296, in do_optim_ghosts
    opt.opti_manager_ghosts(**merged_kwargs)
  File "/home/atari/PycharmProjects/RT/managers/optimisation.py", line 41, in opti_manager_ghosts
    simul_params = simul.fctopti_ghosts(nbrite=1, free_params_ordereddict=free_init_params[-1], **kwargs)   # it returns other stuff we don't need, a,b,c
  File "/home/atari/PycharmProjects/RT/managers/Simulation.py", line 225, in fctopti_ghosts
    popsize=5, callback=self.optim_callback, workers=2)
  File "/home/atari/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py", line 272, in differential_evolution
    ret = solver.solve()
  File "/home/atari/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py", line 701, in solve
    convergence=self.tol / convergence) is True):
  File "/home/atari/PycharmProjects/RT/managers/Simulation.py", line 433, in optim_callback
    optim_value = self.calc_ghost_optimized_value()
  File "/home/atari/PycharmProjects/RT/managers/Simulation.py", line 509, in calc_ghost_optimized_value
    optim_value = np.sum(cubedata[:,:,self.gstart_tick:self.gstop_tick])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Because self.data is None in the context of the optim_callback. This works fine however if I use only 1 core. I am guess that when using multiple cores, the class is serialized and passed around and attributes updated in each process that runs. Then it returns to the main process, where Simulation is still as it was because worker spin-off were called (therefore it still has self.data = None). Meaning I can't easily calculate the optim value, and it seems that although scipy's callback gives me the parameters values all right, it doesn't passes the value I told it those were worth in my model.

Any idea? I guess I could separately re-create a complete model in the optim_callback, update it with the parameters provided, run it again to get the optimization value. However running a model is moderately long and I'd rather not slow down the optimization each and every time I get an (intermediate) optimal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there seems to be no reason why DifferentialEvolution doesn't return the optimization value. Therefore, it's possible to subclasss

```
from scipy.optimize._differentialevolution import DifferentialEvolutionSolver
```

And one only needs to edit a few lines in DifferentialEvolutionSolver.solve() at line 697:

```
     if (self.callback and
             self.callback(self._scale_parameters(self.population[0]),
                           convergence=self.tol / convergence) is True):
```

Becomes:

```
    if (self.callback and
            self.callback(self._scale_parameters(self.population[0]),
                          convergence=self.tol / convergence, optim_value=self.population_energies[0]) is True):
```

As self.population_energies contains the optimizations values thus far, with [0] being the best value at this point.

Therefore in the callback method:

```
def optim_callback(self,*args, **kwargs):
    # *args contains the parameters value for that optimal run
    optim_value = kwargs['optim_value']
    write_optimisation_run_to_dictionnary(args, optim_value)
```

Will provide the optimization value without the need to re-launch the model.